# can't find information on creating a 1TB partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, format

I just formatted my 1TB drive using the instructions here (add https in): help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Then mounted it in my system. When I was verifying the drive, I discovered that fdisk only created a 429.5GB partition. I can't seem to locate any information on getting the entire drive as a partition. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[drive info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DgrS.jpg)

[sudo parted -l results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zMuY.jpg)

```
plex@plex:/media/plex$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/plex--vg-root  222G  173G   38G  83% /
none                       4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                       3.8G   12K  3.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs                      772M  1.4M  771M   1% /run
none                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                       3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /run/shm
none                       100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                  236M   69M  155M  31% /boot
/dev/sdb1                  423G   71M  402G   1% /media/plex/Media1

plex@plex:/dev$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for plex:
Model: ATA ST3250310AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   250GB  250GB  extended
 5      257MB   250GB  250GB  logical                lvm


Model: ATA ST31000524AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1000GB  1000GB  ext3


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/plex--vg-root: 241GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  241GB  241GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/plex--vg-swap_1: 8301MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  8301MB  8301MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Did you use gparted?  What format did you use?

Comment: I used fdisk, when I try to run gparted, I get the following error:

    plex@plex:/dev$ sudo gparted
    
    (gpartedbin:19135): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

and then it drops me back into my prompt. I'm SSH'd into the machine, and it's headless. There's no monitor or keyboard attached anymore. 

'parted' allowed me in, but I don't know anything about it.

also, it's ext3

Comment: what is the output of the command `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I just added a screenshot into the main post because of the character limit

Comment: K - copy-and-paste from the terminal works really well.  I'm a little confused as to why `lsblk` shows a small partition, but `parted` shows a 1 TB partition with an ext3 filesystem.  I think I'll have to leave that for someone smarter than I.

Comment: Yea, I did the copy/paste, and this comment section told me that I was over the limit by 400 characters. :/

And okay thanks. I just don't get this either.

Comment: Stuff lie the screenshots can get copy/pasted into the question itself - that is where the information is generally looked for,

Comment: I'm not an expert on partitioning, but I think it's better to be using ext4. Is there a reason to be using ext3?

Comment: I read the ext3 was good for drives up to 3TB. I can retry partitioning to ext4

Comment: Hmm. It being ext3 shouldn't actually do anything there. Nevermind about that :/

Comment: But I guess doing ext4 can't hurt.

Comment: You didn't create any partition table at all; instead you formatted the entire disk as one 1 tb filesystem, so the premise of your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was just looking into this, here's what I get:

Warning: Partition 1 is 1000GB, but the file system is 461GB.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured that since no one knew what was going on, I would go through the entire process again. I'm not sure what happened the first time, but this time everything worked correctly, and I have the full drive formatted and sdb1 is now the full available space for the drive.